# VS2008 Azure storage client compatibility issue

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2008, azure-storage

According to this article some support for older versions of Azure are going away:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/microsoft-azure-storage-service-version-removal/

We have a vs2008 application that is uploading files to Azure. {Using Azure 1.2 (for VS2008) - Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient v1.0.0 - Runtime v2.0.50727}.

We can't have this break since we are using this in production.

I need to know if there is a clear way to know if this is going to stop working.

I would really like to know if there is a way to upgrade the vs2008 project to use a compatible version of the StorageClient without migrating the project to vs2015.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your version of the library should still be supported after the service removal. You can confirm which version of the service you are hitting by running requests through Fiddler and checking the x-ms-version. As you can see in the most recent [post](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/microsoft-azure-storage-service-version-removal-update-extension-to-2016/) regarding our service deprecation, we are only removing version **2009-07-17** and older as of **August 1, 2016**.